# Put indices inside fmincon function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a problem in using fmincon in Matlab when the variables are using various indices instead of fixed indices. In brief, I have Matlab code as below example:

```
x = fmincon(objfun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)

function f = objfun(x)
  f = a(1,1)*((1 - x(1))*(b(1) + c(1)) + a(2,1)*((1 - x(2))*(b(2) + c(1)) 
    + a(1,2)*((1 - x(1))*(b(1) + c(2)) + a(2,2)*((1 - x(2))*(b(2) + c(2))
end
```

In this case, I want to make a general equation for f as follows:

```
f = a(i,j)*((1 - x(i))*(b(i) + c(j))
```

What do I need to add to f function to realize the same result as the first f formula?

Comment: How about looping over `i` and `j` and find the sum?

Comment: looping inside function f does not work. If I loop outside function f, the fmincon does not work

Comment: Are `a,b,c,x` always of size no more than 2x2?

Comment: It can be more than 2x2. 'i' can be 100, 'j' can be 15

Comment: Why does the loop fails inside the function? What's the error ?

Comment: I can solve this problem by processing the loop process before 'f = '